# Getting a admin-ajax.php error in all actions inside me wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've setup a new website and everything is working fine until when nothing such as finding a plugin or editing elements in visual composer would work. It will just be blank and won't do anything.

It's a new wordpress and I've tried deactivating and reactivating plugins.

POST url:- http://domainame/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: it's not enough description, You face 404 only while you execute ajax call?

Comment: I'd like to explain: When I'm searching plugins in the add new plugin or when I am making changes to elements in the Visual Composer the edit window would just be blank and like wise.

Comment: It's fresh setup or you have edit any file before you do this ?

Comment: No I didn't edit anything at all. The problem just randomly showed up.

Comment: I guess  by mistake you did not included the file which added all your hooks add_action("wp_ajax_get____');

Comment: Please note that I'm not doing any sort of development. So I can't really forget to include the file or add the hooks. It's just a plain install of wordpress which was working fine a day ago.

Comment: Have you deleted Visual composer or just deactive it

Comment: I have deleted and reinstalled. The issue persists with making changes to the elements of VC as well as searching for any plugin or editing or exporting slider revolution sliders.

Comment: have you wrote any custom ajax call inside your functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe a bit more...

But 404 errors in this type of case are mainly caused by a missing enqueued script. You need to add admin-ajax.php as an enqueued script.

In addition, you need to send an action. Can you show us your ajax function ?

You can follow this guide :

https://shellcreeper.com/wp-ajax-for-beginners/

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I am basically not developing a plugin or theme. The issue is generally with my whole website. The admin-ajax.php is there but the error persists.

Comment: Have you tried the classical way : disable all plugins/themes, enable them on after the other... and see when it break your ajax ?